# How many parallel rest API calls can i make with googles cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Im considering of using cloud functions in my project. The project will involve a REST API that will be handled by a cloud functions. While looking at the data Quotas I can see that there is a restrictions for concurrent API calls. This restrictions seam to me quite high.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas

In the documentation for pricing it is stated that for
**API calls (CALL) - Calls to the "call" API** 
there is a restriction of 16 per 100 seconds.

My question is is this a restriction for the REST API that I will build or this is restriction to the firebase/fire cloud internal API?

If not how many cloud functions can execute from my API in a period certain time period in a free tier?

Can I execute 100,000,000 functions triggered from my api in a 100 seconds?

Comment: According to this page, you can only invoke your function 125,000 per month in the free tier.  If you are willing to pay, you can support a load of 100M every 100 seconds.   - https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Kolban :)

Answer (score 1):

The "API Calls (READ)" limit doesn't affect the way you function is invoked directly from HTTP requests.  It's a limit on Cloud Functions API requests that describe your functions.  It's not for direct invocations of your function.

The limit that describes how your function is actually invoked is "Functions invocations per second", which is 100,000,000 per 100 seconds.  This is for your own APIs that you create.